# How to apply the common design for all database?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am having a thirty of notes databases. Each database has more than 20 forms and fifty views approximately. We planned for design change [Style of form, Action bar, View, tables and etc.,]. We designed a common style and applied to a database. Now Is their anyway to apply the design directly for all database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If those other databases have the same 20+ forms and the same 50+ views, creating and refreshing the design via a template is the perfect way to do it.

If, on the other hand, you mean that you've come up with a set of standards for formatting forms, action bars, views, tables and such, you've got a far different task at hand. If you do have some literal Notes design elements (forms, views, subforms) that are identical (or ought to be identical) across the databases, you can assign templates to those individual elements and use templates to just refresh those elements. If the dissimilar elements are few, you could assign a template for the database, but either exempt the dissimilar elements or mark them as inheriting from a different template.

So, it depends on the standardization of specific design elements across those current databases. If they all ought to be exactly the same (not just look the same) then it's easy. If your goal is only look-and-feel similarity, your task will be more complicated.

I know there are new tools with the Designer client and others provided by third-parties that enhance your ability to discover and find-and-replace items, but your goal may be beyond what's available. So, it might end up being a mostly manual process.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the design changes in a template and let the databases inheret design from that template. If you run the [design](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/7.0/help7_designer.nsf/855dc7fcfd5fec9a85256b870069c0ab/943b12488c6ea36e8525704a003f6ed7?OpenDocument) task at night, it will update the design in all the databases.

Comment: Actually there are 50 different databases. So we need to create 50 template?

Comment: If you want the designs to be identical, you only need one template. If the 50 databases are supposed to have different designs, then you need 50 templates (or, as I noted in my answer in the 20th, some combination of templates for the similar and dissimilar design elements).